# set number picker am pm value dynamically

Tags: android, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I am working on custom number picker for displaying AM and PM values.Please check the below code for number picker.

```
<com.naushad.kenocustomer.util.NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/np_ampm"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

XML code looks like this and below is the java code.

```
    final String ampm[] = {"AM", "PM"};
            datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setFormatter(R.string.number_picker_formatter);

            datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setSelectedTextColor(Color.parseColor("#09bcf2"));
            datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#babdc2"));
            datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setDefaultSelectedTextSize(20);
            datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fifteen));

            datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setMinValue(1);
            datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setMaxValue(ampm.length);
            datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setDisplayedValues(ampm);
int isAM = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        int myValue = Arrays.asList(ampm).indexOf(String.valueOf(isAM));
        if(isAM == 0)
            datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setValue(Integer.parseInt(ampm[1].toString()));
        else
            datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setValue(Integer.parseInt(ampm[1].toString()));
```

now i am going to set number picker value dynamically as per the current time.but i have written code in following way and getting the **number format exception.**

I want to set am pm value to number picker as per the current time.Please suggest me how can i achieve that.thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting your error somewhere around here?

```
 if(isAM == 0)
        datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setValue(Integer.parseInt(ampm[1].toString()));
    else
        datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setValue(Integer.parseInt(ampm[1].toString()));
```

That seems reasonable since `ampm[1]` contains the String "AM" and in

```
Integer.parseInt(ampm[1].toString())
```

you try to parse that into an integer but "AM" is not a Number but a String. Therefore a

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "PM"
```

Exception is totally reasonable. If you want to display it as a string get rid of the `Integer.parseInt(...)`. I don't know what your `datetimeBinding.npAmpm` exactly is, but if it is a normal label set it like this?

```
datetimeBinding.npAmpm.setValue(ampm[1]);
```

(Also: In both cases of `if(isAM == 0)` you are using `ampm[1]`, I guess one of those should be `ampm[0]`)

Comment: yes you are right i get the exception on same line.

Comment: yes as I explained. you cannot cast "AM" to a number since "AM" is NOT a number.

Comment: But how can i change AM PM Value dynamically??

Comment: I explained to you where your exception is coming from. If you want to change it dynamically you have to add a listener in the viewholder and change the values inside this listener.

Comment: But as per your explanation it doesn't take any string values inside of the setValue().It only allow int values as a parameter..

Comment: As already mentioned, I don't know how that library you are using there works in detail. I just pointed out your obvious error that you cannot parse a String to a Number. Maybe you have to pass 0 and 1 inside it, have you tried that?

Comment: its databinding library.By using this we cannot use findViewById().yes i tried but no luck..

Comment: I resolved this issue by passing 1 and 2 values to setValue()